# How can I output the replacetokens in a YAML pipeline with Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm using the task 'replacetokens@4' and it says 'replaced 6 tokens out of 6 tokens in 1 file', but I want to view the output of the replacetokens. How can I do this?

Comment: Run a script and echo the contents of the file to stdout

Answer (score 2):

> I want to view the output of the replacetokens. How can I do this?

Agree with Daniel. You can run the script to output the file content to pipeline log.

Here is a PowerShell script example:

```
steps:
- powershell: 'Get-Content -Path filepath/filename'
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

In addition, you can use [Publish Pipeline Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) to publish the target file to Pipeline artifacts.

Then you can download the file in Pipeline artifacts and check the content.

[image]